# Practical case on Symfony2 validation constraint expression

Tags: validation, symfony, expression, constraints, yaml

I'm currently fighting with ExpressionLanguage validation regarding to a constraint wanted on form validation :

My form :

- Text item
- Entity1 item selector (dropdown)
- Entity2 item selector (dropdown)
- Textarea item

My wishes :

- One error trigger on condition *Text Item* is empty and *Entity1* selector is empty
- Another error trigger on condition : `Entity1.id == XX` and `Entity2.id == YY` and Textarea is empty

So far, I got this in validation.yml :

```
Experveo\ShopBundle\Entity\Vehicle:
    constraints:
        - Expression:
            expression: "this.getTextItem() != '' |  this.getEntity1() != ''"
            message: error1.
```

It seems I need to put **the opposite condition** to make it work. So far I didn't find any advanced clue on [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html), nor [in expression language syntax help](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html).

How can I achieve those conditions? Following is not working at all...

```
- Expression:    
    expression: >
        this.getTextItem() == ''
        && this.getEntity1() != ''
        && this.getEntity1().getId() === 49
        && this.getEntity2() != ''
        && this.getEntity2() === 914
        && this.getTextAreaItem() == ''"
    message: error2.
```

Comment: When you're getting this complex I might look at [creating a custom validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html), especially seeing hardcoded values like that.  It also seems like you'd want to check `== ''` for your two entities, not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would say your answer is the "big" tool, allowing even more complex validation patterns and logic. The Callback I suggest below suited my needs. But thank you for pointing me this lead.

Comment: No problem - the nice thing about Symfony is that flexibility to do either and not always require the most complex solution to solve a simple problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. As I run on 2.4 and according to [this fix](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/11590) merged later on, the ExpressionValidator was incorrectly skipping validation of null or empty string values.

Therefore, the callback option is a correct workaround, as mentionned in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649713/assert-expression-validation-not-working-at-attribute-level-in-symfony-2-4). In my case :

```
 /**
 * @Assert\Callback
 *
 * Using a callback is a better solution insted of make an "Assert\Expression" for the class,
 * because of a Symfony bug where the ExpressionValidator skip validating if the value if empty or null.
 * Exemple for information : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649713/assert-expression-validation-not-working-at-attribute-level-in-symfony-2-4
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if( '' === $this->getTextItem() && '' === $this->getMark() ){
        $context->buildViolation("error 1")
            ->addViolation();
    }

    if( '' === $this->getTextItem()
        && '' === $this->getTextAreaItem()
        && (( $this->getEntity1() && $this->getEntity1()->getId() === self::ENTITY1_VALUE)
             || ($this->getEntity2() && $this->getEntity2()->getId() === self::ENTITY2_VALUE))  
    ){
        $context->buildViolation("error2")
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```